# How does the skill upgrade system work?

Tags: dmc-devil-may-cry

I've played a few missions so far, and have gotten a handful of skill upgrade points. As I've purchased new skills, I've noticed that you can "sell" skills that you've chosen and get your upgrade points back. Is there any limit to this? Do you at some point need to stick with your decisions, or can you freely exchange your skills forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell you can move points around freely, even ones you bought before. I don't think there's any sort of penalty for it either.

Comment: You cannot remove points in the basic moves that the game gifts do you (Demon/Angel pull, basic shoot for each gun), but all points that you manually assigned can be removed through the same screen.  Also, the only "penalty" is there is a statistic for number of times points were moved around - fun to see how indecisive a player might be.